# Xamarin project The specified IOS Provisioning Profile {my profile} could not be found

Tags: xamarin

I get "Xamarin project The specified IOS Provisioning Profile {my profile} could not be found", when I compile my solution.

I thought this was a runtime error.

When I go to options->IOS Bundle Signing, there is a dropdown in Provisioning Profile, with options {my profile} and Unknown.

So research says, that {my profile} is old, or I need to be linked to this profile.  If I change my Provisioning Profile to Unknown, will this solve the compile problem?  Will {my profile} not be available in the future?

Can you please tell me how I can get around this error and run IOS in simulator?

Comment: You need to go to the Apple developer site and generate a profile

Comment: Please specify which VS version you are using and whether you're running it on Windows or macOS. If you don't have a provisioning profile and development certificate yet, you'll need to create it on https://developer.apple.com. If your profile has expired, you need to create a new one.

Answer (score 1):

You could enter your Apple Developer Account, find the provisioning profile you used and edit with right App ID, Certificates and Devices. Then download and refresh the profile.

[image: just like this]

or just generate a new profile then use it.

Hope it could help.